# DroidGap: TIMEOUT ERROR! - calling webViewClient in android phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, timeout, droidgap

I am developing a android mobile application using PhoneGap.When I am trying to invoke a webservice from the javascript,I am getting DroidGap: TIMEOUT ERROR! - calling webViewClient in android phonegap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to increase the timeout value in the onCreate method of your Java class that extends DroidGap

```
super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);
```

Comment: issue is only for single call or all the call?

Comment: Single call only.I am new to android mobile app development using Phonegap.

Comment: How much time is taking webservice for returning value check that depending upon that increase the timeout

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have updated your PhoneGap's whitelist to allow access to any external domains. Check [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide) for the PhoneGap documentation.