# Cordova webview TIMEOUT ERROR

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, android-webview

I've tried to use the following code:

```
cordovaWebView = (CordovaWebView) findViewById(R.id.cordovaWebView);
cordovaWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

And I get various URLs injecting javascript like this:

```
cordovaWebView.loadUrl("javascript:CreateFormPlugin.showPage('1')");
```

But sometimes I get this issue:

```
12-12 11:56:32.561: E/dalvikvm(27065): JNI ERROR (app bug): attempt to use stale local reference 0x1
12-12 11:56:32.561: E/dalvikvm(27065): VM aborting
12-12 11:56:32.561: A/libc(27065): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1)
12-12 11:56:41.951: E/CordovaWebView(27065): CordovaWebView: TIMEOUT ERROR!
```

Any idea on how to solve this problem? :)

Thanks!

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: 2.6, now I'm trying to update to 2.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I did it this way: [set loadURLTImeOutValue on webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772409/set-loadurltimeoutvalue-on-webview)

i.e. adding intent.putExtra("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000); to every call to the activity that extends CordovaInterface.

Answer (score 3):

You need to increase the timeout value

```
super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 70000);
```

See this link 
[DroidGap: TIMEOUT ERROR! - calling webViewClient in android phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120078/droidgap-timeout-error-calling-webviewclient-in-android-phonegap/18120692#18120692)

Comment: yes but where? I don't use the DroidGap class, I have only the CordoveWebActivity :(

Comment: in oncreate method,in your application startup class

Comment: a normal activity doesn't have that method (or at least I'm doing something wrong!)

Comment: Where do you call the startup HTML page

Answer (score -1):

I search so much for this thing and i am now in the all most conclusion that it is because the speed of the net..will developing apps then use speed internet so between your work you not get any error and until for this problem there is no solution from cordova..so when you publish that time it will remove...